# How to remove specific users logged in to my website using Facebook single signon?

Tags: fbconnect

There are plenty of threads out there discussing "how can a user remove permission for an app". I would like to know the opposite: How can I remove a user who is connected to my app using facebook single signon? The user pressed the facebook login-button and user logged in to my website by facebook login. Now i need to get list of users who are connected using fb login and need to delete those users.
Thanks in advance.